# JQuery Problems to build Progressbar

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to setup a simple Progress-Bar, but however the "update" is performed, but only when "all" ajax requests are finished?

Start of Request;

```
   $(".cb-download").colorbox({
    opacity:.8,
    onComplete:function() {
        $.colorbox.resize();
        if (ERROR !== true) {
           // update Progress
           var progress = setInterval(updateProgress, 100);
      
           $.ajax({
                url: baseUrl + "/mail/do-download",
                async: true,
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#mail-download").html(data);
                    $.colorbox.resize();
                    clearInterval(progress);
                }
            });
        } else {
            $('#mail-download-success').hide();
            $('#mail-download-session-lost').show();
            $.colorbox.resize();
        }
    }
});

function updateProgress()
{
$.ajax({
    url: baseUrl + "/mail/get-progress",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $("#current-count").html(data);
    }
});
}
```

updateProgess is just calling an action which echoes a number.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Found my Solution.

The PHP Session was locking the Session file, so the second request was waiting for the first one (file lock).

No iam using

```
session_write_close();
```

when the long running script starts. The Progress is now written to an Database/File instead of the session. Works very well.